# Find declaration of large array

Tags: .net, profiling, dotmemory

dotMemory indicates that one of my user's application instances has a sparsely populated byte array of length 20,971,520 that is wasting 160MB. This is from a process dump analysis.

Is there a way to find where this array is declared/used from the process dump? I also have the solution code to hand.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not clear from the retention path? If so, profile (run under profiling) the application with dotMemory with collection of allocations data turned on, then look where this array is instantiated.